# Why a pointer to no object can be asked to execute a setter?

Tags: objective-c, setter

I creating a pointer does not create a Class object.
But it can be send method to execute in another instance method. 
I think just a pointer to the object can be asked to execute a method.

Why the "t" can use setter in the method like this image?
[image]

[image]

Comment: See [Working with `nil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22) in _Programming with Objective-C,_ which says "A `nil` value is the safest way to initialize an object pointer if you don’t have another value to use, because it’s perfectly acceptable in Objective-C to send a message to `nil`. If you do send a message to `nil`, obviously nothing happens." So, if `t` is `nil`, sending it a message (including calling a setter for a property) does nothing.

Comment: Just a few years ago, we'd have to remind everyone that this only works this way in ARC.  In pre-ARC days, `t` would be an un-initialized variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Xcode only checks if declared type of `t` variable has visible readwrite property named `a`. It doesn't care if `t` is actually object or something else at this point. For example, it cannot know if `t` is object or nil, or anything else in such situation

```
- (void) method:(One*) t{
     t.a = @"Some string";
}
```

You can call it like this

```
[two method:nil];
```

Xcode won't complain. You can even do this

```
One *t = (One *)[[NSObject alloc] init];   //warning here
t.a = @"Some t";                           //Xcode doesn't care, that t is actually NSObject and doesn't respond to setA:; But you get a runtime error
```

`nil` in ObjC responds to all selectors - you can call any visible method on nil object and you won't get a warning nor error. Just silently passes by